# Script to return an email address from the sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an observation form, that loads an email address when the observed teachers' name is selected.

I wanted the form to email the observed teacher as a pdf, and then clear, so it could be used over and over without having to make a copy each time.

I found 2 different peoples' web pages where they offered scripts to accomplish this and was able to put them together and get them to work. However, the script that sends the form as an email, requires me to type the email on the script page, and I have to use my email. I want it to load the observed teachers' email, which is in cell D5 on a sheet called "Walk Thru"

Thanks for any help.

```
function sendReport() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Set Up").hideSheet();
  var message = {
    to: "myemailaddress@gmail.com",
    subject: "Walk Through Observation",
    body: "Hello,\n\nPlease find the recent walk through observation attached.\n\nThank you.",
   
    attachments: [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getAs(MimeType.PDF).setName("Walk Through Observation")]
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail(message);
  
{
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    
  var teacher = sheet.getRange("c4").clearContent();
    var box1 = sheet.getRange("l8").clearContent(); 
    var box2 = sheet.getRange("m8").clearContent();
    var box3 = sheet.getRange("n8").clearContent();
    var box4 = sheet.getRange("o8").clearContent();
    var box5 = sheet.getRange("l9").clearContent(); 
    var box6 = sheet.getRange("m9").clearContent();       
    var box7 = sheet.getRange("n9").clearContent(); 
    var box9 = sheet.getRange("o9").clearContent(); 
    var box10 = sheet.getRange("l10").clearContent();
    var box11 = sheet.getRange("m10").clearContent();
    var box12 = sheet.getRange("n10").clearContent();
    var box13 = sheet.getRange("o10").clearContent(); 
    var box14 = sheet.getRange("l11").clearContent();       
    var box15 = sheet.getRange("m11").clearContent();   
    var box16 = sheet.getRange("n11").clearContent();
    var box17 = sheet.getRange("o11").clearContent();
    var box18 = sheet.getRange("l12").clearContent();
    var box19 = sheet.getRange("m12").clearContent(); 
    var box20 = sheet.getRange("n12").clearContent();       
    var box21 = sheet.getRange("o12").clearContent();    
    var comment1 = sheet.getRange("b14").clearContent();    

    var box1 = sheet.getRange("l16").clearContent(); 
    var box2 = sheet.getRange("m16").clearContent();
    var box3 = sheet.getRange("n16").clearContent();
    var box4 = sheet.getRange("o16").clearContent();
    var box5 = sheet.getRange("l17").clearContent(); 
    var box6 = sheet.getRange("m17").clearContent();       
    var box7 = sheet.getRange("n17").clearContent(); 
    var box9 = sheet.getRange("o17").clearContent(); 
    var box10 = sheet.getRange("l18").clearContent();
    var box11 = sheet.getRange("m18").clearContent();
    var box12 = sheet.getRange("n18").clearContent();
    var box13 = sheet.getRange("o18").clearContent(); 
    var box14 = sheet.getRange("l19").clearContent();       
    var box15 = sheet.getRange("m19").clearContent();   
    var box16 = sheet.getRange("n19").clearContent();
    var box17 = sheet.getRange("o19").clearContent();
    var comment2 = sheet.getRange("b21").clearContent();  

    var box1 = sheet.getRange("l23").clearContent(); 
    var box2 = sheet.getRange("m23").clearContent();
    var box3 = sheet.getRange("n23").clearContent();
    var box4 = sheet.getRange("o23").clearContent();
    var box5 = sheet.getRange("l24").clearContent(); 
    var box6 = sheet.getRange("m24").clearContent();       
    var box7 = sheet.getRange("n24").clearContent(); 
    var box9 = sheet.getRange("o24").clearContent(); 
    var box10 = sheet.getRange("l25").clearContent();
    var box11 = sheet.getRange("m25").clearContent();
    var box12 = sheet.getRange("n25").clearContent();
    var box13 = sheet.getRange("o25").clearContent(); 
    var box14 = sheet.getRange("l26").clearContent();       
    var box15 = sheet.getRange("m26").clearContent();   
    var box16 = sheet.getRange("n26").clearContent();
    var box17 = sheet.getRange("o26").clearContent();
    var box18 = sheet.getRange("l27").clearContent();
    var box19 = sheet.getRange("m27").clearContent(); 
    var box20 = sheet.getRange("n27").clearContent();       
    var box21 = sheet.getRange("o27").clearContent();    
    var comment3 = sheet.getRange("b29").clearContent();    


    var box1 = sheet.getRange("l31").clearContent(); 
    var box2 = sheet.getRange("m31").clearContent();
    var box3 = sheet.getRange("n31").clearContent();
    var box4 = sheet.getRange("o31").clearContent();
    var box5 = sheet.getRange("l32").clearContent(); 
    var box6 = sheet.getRange("m32").clearContent();       
    var box7 = sheet.getRange("n32").clearContent(); 
    var box9 = sheet.getRange("o32").clearContent(); 
    var box10 = sheet.getRange("l33").clearContent();
    var box11 = sheet.getRange("m33").clearContent();
    var box12 = sheet.getRange("n33").clearContent();
    var box13 = sheet.getRange("o33").clearContent(); 
    var comment4 = sheet.getRange("b35").clearContent();    

    var comment5 = sheet.getRange("d37").clearContent();    

     var observer = sheet.getRange("d39").clearContent();    




  
}
  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the [getValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) method:

> Returns the value of the top-left cell in the range. The value may be of type Number, Boolean, Date, or String depending on the value of the cell. Empty cells return an empty string.

For example:
`var email = sheet.getRange("D5").getValue();`

Also, you should optimize your code, as it's unnecessary to get the ranges one by one. The [getRange(a1Notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation) method says:

> Returns the range as specified in A1 notation or R1C1 notation.

This means you can specify several rows and columns. For example: `sheet.getRange(A2:F3).clearContent();` would clear rows 2 and 3 from columns A to F.

Regarding the `clearContent()`, you don't need to declare a variable for each one (you are also repeating names, remember a [variable](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/javascript/javascript-variable) assigns a value to a specific space of the memory, so are overwriting box1, 2 etc with each declaration). You can also declare the ranges first and group them to clear the content with just one instruction. To do so, use a [RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list).

The final code would be:

```
function sendReport() {
    var sprsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    sprsheet.getSheetByName("Set Up").hideSheet();

    var email = sheet.getRange("D5").getValue();
    var message = {
        to: email,
        subject: "Walk Through Observation",
        body: "Hello,\n\nPlease find the recent walk through observation attached.\n\nThank you.",

        attachments: [sprsheet.getAs(MimeType.PDF).setName("Walk Through Observation")]
    }

    MailApp.sendEmail(message);

    var rangeList = sheet.getRangeList(['C4', 'L8:O12', 'B14', 'B21', 'L23:O27', 'B29', 'L31:O33', 'B35', 'D27', 'D39']);

    rangeList.clearContent();
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I greatly appreciate you taking the time to do this.
It works amazingly well. 

You are wonderful!!!!!!!

Comment: You are welcome! Please consider accepting my answer, so others can benefit from it :)